# Invalid argument (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107) (UnknownCommandException)

Tags: php, google-chrome, behat, browserstack

> ```
> FeatureContext::iAmOnSite()
>       invalid argument
>         (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107) (UnknownCommandException)
> ```

I am getting error while trying to run the browserstack with behat.

below is my conf.

```
default:
  autoload: ['%paths.base%/../src/context']
  suites:
      default:
          paths: [ '%paths.base%/../features' ]
          contexts:
              - FeatureContext:
                   parameters:
                        server: 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com'
                        user: '<username>'
                        key: '<access_key>'
                        capabilities:
                            # capabilities added here are applied to every test that is run
                            name: "Behat - local test"
                            build: "behat-browserstack"
                            record_video: "true"
                            record_network: "true"
                            max_duration: 300 # time in seconds
                            browserstack.use_w3c: "True"
                            browserstack.selenium_version: "3.141.59"
                        browsers:
                            # each item in this list is run as a single test
                            # so to run multiple tests in parallel,
                            # simply define multiple browsers below and run the test with
                            # $ php run-parallel.php -c config/<filename>.yml
                            -
                                os_api_name: "Win10"
                                browser_api_name: "Edge"
                                resolution: "1920x1080"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're executing the test on BrowserStack, try using the capabilities from their [capabilities generator](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities) to get the correct capabilities for your tests.

Also, try using the sample config provided in their Behat documentation: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/getting-started/php/behat#introduction

If that doesn't fix your issue, I would suggest reaching out to their support team with your session ID.